# JVMJ9GC020E -Xms too large for heap

Tags: java, jvm

I am using `${JAVA_HOME}/java -Xms512m`

I am getting an error :

```
---------------------------------------------------
JVMJ9GC020E -Xms too large for heap
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc23(2): Failed to initialize
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
--------------------------------------------------
```

we have 32 bit JVM . can this be solved without updating JVM to 64 bit ?

Comment: Only `-Xms` and not `-Xmx`? Also, which JVM is that? Oracle's, another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try also setting a value for `Xmx`:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M
```

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms), the default value of `Xmx` is usually `256MB`, which is less than what you specified for `Xms`.  `Xmx` controls the maximum heap size, and if `Xms` were larger than the available maximum, it might explain the error you are seeing.

`4GB` is the largest address which can be supported by a 32 bit system, but your `Xms` value is not really close to this.